# Is it possible in a maven/spring build to load transitive dependencies in private classloaders?

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, packaging

I find myself spending much to much time solving conflicts between versions of transitive dependencies. I whish it would be possible to load these using  private embedded classloaders, so multiple versions of the same library could be (indirectly) used by different components. As most beans of a well-designed application depend only on a limited number of external libraries and data-centric model classes of the application, it seems to me that spring generated bean proxies could load bean implementation (and libraries used by it) in a child classloader.

I admit I never worked directly with a multi-classloader application (aside from a Java EE environment), so it is not obvious to me if and how such packaging would be possible. Are there any spring & maven/sbt plugins which allow it? Or maybe just good articles on creating multi-artifact, multi-classloader builds?

Comment: What you want (or maybe not) is OSGI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).

Comment: Which dependencies are causing trouble? Spring Boot's dependency management should help to a large extent. If you need more, the Spring IO Platform offers a superset of Boot's dependency management.

Comment: An OSGI container is the kind of environment that can manage this use case.  HOWEVER,  that being said I currently work in an OSGI environment and it is quite the pain.  I strongly recommend leveraging Spring boot's prepackaged and tested dependencies together to avoid multiple dependency clashes.  When you move to an OSGI container there is a lot of dependencies that have not been packaged with OSGI in mind and could cause problems.  Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Last one to cause problems was elastic search (spring-boot has no artifact for versions 2.3), but I encountered similar problems with other libraries. Quite often a library I picked personally depends on a different version of some thrid party library than spring-boot stack. I feel like it should really be possible to mark dependencies as 'implementation' or 'interface' and load the former in a separate class loader, just as we avoid name clashes using packages.. OSGI indeed looks like it would solve it, but it does much more and indeed might increase complexity more than is necessary.

Comment: I played a bit with a simple custom ClassLoader implementation and it looks like it's not only possible, but also quite easy to implement in principle. The complexity would be a maven/sbt plugin for managing such dependencies and of course application framework integration.

Comment: @Turin writing a custom CL is more work than it seems, and if not done right may cause more troubles than it does any good. Especially when you want to handle the dynamic unloading of classes. [This plugin architecture](https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication) I wrote for a university course, checks the JARs MANIFEST.FM for exported and dependent classes (which is not 100% Java conform) to load JARs only if certain dependen classes were provided by other JARs which marked them as exported. These shared classes are loaded by a separate common CL which is a delegate parent to the plugin CL